# How to get FSharpCore.Dll to work in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, f#

Some time ago after an update I managed to get an F# classlibrary working in unity however since another unity update I suddenly get error messages again, in particular unity can not load the FSharpCore.Dll I placed inside its Asset folder. Getting desperate any help welcome

FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'FSharp.Core, Version=4.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.

Comment: Why are you copying a dll manually, instead of just referencing the FSharp.Core nuget package?

Comment: Have you tried to do this from a Unity3D Project? Personally I lack exprience with these things, I tried to follow your proposal regardless. Results: 1 Unity3d does not support nuget that easily 2 Downloading per nuget from another project and then adding the FSharpCore.Dll as a dependency also did not work.

Comment: Sorry I do not know Unity3D and it seems my advice was not good. It does look like the tooling for Unity is different from and not as streamlined as the rest of .Net and in particular nuget is not standard. https://www.davideaversa.it/2018/04/quick-look-at-f-in-unity/ does mention copying in dlls. Sorry I cannot help on this one.